# installing VpnClientSetupAmd64.exe without prompt through commandline

Tags: powershell, cmd

Installation problem of this file as per default behaviour by double click.
File was downloaded from Azure VPN Client.

I have tried extracting it and then using connection manager service profile execution but all in vain. 
Steps followed are given below:

1. VpnClientSetupAmd64.exe /T:{Extracted directory} /C
2. cmstp /s /au {guid}.inf

More information about file:
- file type: application .exe
- description: Win32 Cabinet Self-Extractor
- original filename: wextract.exe .mui
- Archive: Sfx CAB archive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1):

First hit on google shows the following:

Direct quote from the Azure Networking Team -

> *"Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this is a Windows VPN*
>   *platform constraint. Azure P2S VPN package will add network routes on*
>   *the machine, which will require admin privilege and will trigger UAC*
>   *prompt on Windows. This is not an Azure specific constraint."*

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/17506417-silent-install-for-p2s-vpn-package-file